# PDO PHP: оставить в базе прежнее значение

Tags: php, pdo

Есть код:

```
$q = $db->prepare('UPDATE table1 SET val1 = :val1, val2 = :val2 WHERE name = :name');
$q->execute(array(':val1' => $_POST["val1"], ':name' => 'Example'));
```

Как видно из примера, я присваиваю новые значения `val1` и `val2`. Проблема в том, что изменяемых ячеек у меня более 20, но часть из них может не требовать изменений (отсутствуют обновляемые значения). Можно сконструировать сам запрос и массив со значениями на if’ах, но это очень некрасиво.

Может, можно как-то по-другому? Чтобы в БД писались лишь те значения, которые получены?

Что-то вроде:

```
$values = ['val1' => $_POST["val1"], 'name' => 'Example'];
$values[:val2] = (isset($_POST["val2"])) ? $_POST["val2"] : null;
$q->execute($values);
```

Comment: [COALESCE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) Запрос будет типа такого: `UPDATE table1 SET val1 = COALESCE(:val1, val1), val2 = COALESCE(:val2, val2) WHERE name = :name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@turambar Можно сделать по такому подобию.

```
$fields = [];
$params[':name'] = 'Example';

array_walk($$_POST, function ($value, $field) use(&$fields, &$params) {
    $fieldParam = ':' . $field;
    $fields[] = $field . ' = ' . $fieldParam;
    $params[$fieldParam] = $value;
});

$q = $db->prepare('UPDATE table1 SET ' . implode(', ', $fields) . ' WHERE name = :name');
$q->execute($params);
```